Link2SD issue with linking data folders
I only use Link2SD to link my game files to external storage, a straightforward and short process, then I'm able to play these games with their data sitting on my SD card
Everything went to shit after I flashed my phone and upgraded to Android 12, Link2SD links my game data to my SD card, the only problem is when I launch the games, the games don't recognize the link and they create a new data folder in /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/Android/data.
I downgraded to Android 11 but a slightly newer ROM than what I started with, same issues and it's very frustrating, I only have 64gb internal storage and I've managed to play Genshin Impact and Honkai Star rail until this whole fiasco.
I've tried in-built adoptable storage, and adoptable storage with apps2sd, but nothing. Now I'm looking at downgrading to Android 10 and trying Fbind but I've been reading some stuff online and I'm wondering if this all stems from my SD card not using a Linux Filesystem, Please correct me because I really don't know what I'm doing
Any tips will be appreciated, thanks.

Does this answer your question? Link2SD - Game ignores binded data after link

you have linked /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/Android/data? can you show screenshot "I don't do anything fancy like creating a second partition" you can't link anything without 2nd partition - you're probably talking about something else, like Android native App2SD

I used Link2SD to link the Data(Ext) folder to the primary and only partition on my SD card formatted to default portable storage, my game data was in a /externalsd/Link2SD/bind folder along with the rest of my files, so now it does that but the game doesn't recognise the link anymore and writes new data where it would normally be in internal storage, and this was only after I flashed my device.
